# Buttons displaying wrong colors when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My website contains buttons, each representing a color which should change the color of the container div if the user clicks on one, this up until recently worked but now when I click for a color, what i'll actually be getting is the next color up in my array which holds color codes, hoping someone can help me figure out why I'm getting different colors to what the buttons should be giving me

A link to code pen containing my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myfjn

```
$("document").ready( function (){

var noteColourArray = [];
noteColourArray[0] = "#03CEC2"; 
noteColourArray[1] = "#ADC607";
noteColourArray[2] = "#ffdd00";
noteColourArray[3] = "#f7941f";

//Loop through noteColourArray and append new button for each item
for (var i = 0, len = noteColourArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    noteCreate.noteCreateContainer.append($("<button>", {class: "colourSelect", value: noteColourArray[i] }).css("background-color", noteColourArray[i]).click(setBackgroundColour)) 
}

function setBackgroundColour()
{
    $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index()] )
    return false;
}

});
```

Comment: Please add the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the function setBackgroundColour like below;

```
function setBackgroundColour()
{
    $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index() - 1] )
    return false;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqepC

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    #stickerList 
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 3rem;
    background-color:grey;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

To:

```
    #stickerList 
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 3rem;

    margin-top: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function from:

```
  function setBackgroundColour()
  {
      $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index()] );
    return false;
  }
```

TO:

```
 function setBackgroundColour()
  {
      $("#noteCreateContainer").css("background-color", noteColourArray[$(this).index()-1] );
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: thanks that fixed it, mark this as answer as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 0):

```
var noteColourArray = [];
noteColourArray[0] = "#03CEC2"; 
noteColourArray[1] = "#ADC607";
noteColourArray[2] = "#ffdd00";
noteColourArray[3] = "#f7941f";

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < noteColourArray.length; i++) {
        $('body').append('<button class="colorize">Press Me!</button>');
    }

    $('button.colorize').click(function(){
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', noteColourArray[$(this).index()]);
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2s8SW/1/